# Method Always Returning True

Tags: java

```
    public static boolean checkGuess(String getGuess, double getBet){
    double num = Math.round(Math.random()*10);
    boolean correctSide = false;
    if (num <=5 && getGuess.equals("H")){
        correctSide = true;
    } else if (num >=6 && getGuess.equals("T")){
        correctSide = true;
    } else {
        correctSide = false;
    }
    updateBal(correctSide, getBet);
    return correctSide;
}
```

For some reason, this ALWAYS returns true.
Any ideas why?

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: Impossible. `Math.round(Math.random())` is always 1.

Comment: @ohaleck Sometimes it's `0`.

Comment: All your logic can be  `correctSide = num == 0 && (getGuess.equals("H") || getGuess.equals("T") );`

Comment: @ohaleck: how many times did you run it ? :)

Comment: anyways if getguess is not h or t then it shld be false

Comment: Looks like you want to use `Random#nextBoolean()` as well as enums for Coin.HEADS and Coin.TAILS.

Comment: I ran it in a loop, and it returned true 20 times.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard you're right. I used http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ to quickly test the code. Their RNG is certainly not working very well :)

Comment: @ModifyYou: Again, **WHAT IS THIS CODE SUPPOSED TO DO?**

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's a coin-flip betting game, evidently.

Comment: Updated the OP with an updated version, but still not working. It's supposed to be a Heads or Tails game. I can post the full code if needed...

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: I know that, but this code above is a bit "unusual". If getGuess is always H or T, then the if block is meaningless and should only return the result of num < or > regardless of getGuess's value. It's fck'd up code. At Modify You: details please. Again, do a little debugging please.

Comment: You just changed the code in the post. Does this still always return `true`? Have you tried printing out `num` to ensure it's giving the values you're expecting?

Comment: Have you tried any other debugging (such as printing out every variable at different points to make sure the values are what you think they should be)?

Comment: The first if else pair returns nothing more than if num == 0.

Comment: Show us how you call it, i.e. how are you choosing H,T? Randomly? I confirm that your checkguess logic works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There it is:

```
 public static double updateBal(boolean correctSide, double getBet){
            double balance = getBal();
            if (correctSide = true){
                    balance = getBet * 2 + balance;
                    System.out.println("Correct. Your balance is now $" + balance);
            } else {
                    balance = balance - getBet;
                    System.out.println("Incorrect. Your balance is now $" + balance);
            }
            return balance;
    }
```

You have to check with: if(correctSide == true). You currently do correctSide = true and so you always say correctSide is true.

Comment: So the method wasn't returning true, but rather `updateBal` was always adding the bet.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and following part seems to work correctly:

```
double num = Math.round(Math.random());
boolean correctSide = false;
if (num == 0 && getGuess.equals("H")){
    correctSide = true;
} else if (num == 0 && getGuess.equals("T")){
    correctSide = true;
} else {
    correctSide = false;
}
return correctSide;
```

Please also share what you do in updateBal(correctSide, getBet);

Comment: Math.round(Math.random()) is not always returning 1. Math.random() returns a value between 0 and 1 and Math.round() has the following implementation:                                                           public static long round( double a ) {
  return (int) floor( a + 0.5f );
}